# Element.text data loss

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing a web scraper, which collects data from a sport site. There are tables where I want to write the text from each tr into an array. In some lines it isnt possible to get the whole text.

While debugging at a breakpoint after t=...

```
element_table = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//table//tbody//tr')))

for count, e in enumerate(element_table):
    if count > 3:
        line = e.text.splitlines()
        t = e.text
```

in the debugger e's text was

```
text= {str} 'Salzburg\n4-3-1-2\n57%\n2 1.42\n14/4\n28.57%\n594/489\n82.32%\n66.7\n130\n12/43/75\n108\n38/48/22\n210/85\n40.48%'
```

but when I look at t

```
t = {str} 'Salzburg\n4-3-1-2\n2 1.42\n14/4\n594/489\n66.7\n130\n108\n210/85',
```

so does element.text not get me all the text that is in the tr? Also it happens just on few lines.

the line that doesnt work and then some line that does work:

```
<tr>
<td>Salzburg</td>
            <td class="Index__video-cell-widget___3PDlg"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ"><em>4-3-1-2</em><small>57%</small></span></td>
            <td class="Index__video-cell___s1IHu"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ">2</span><div class="Index__video-cell-icon___3Pnub"></div></td>
            <td class="Index__simple-cell-widget___1BYWx"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ">1.42</span></td>
            <td class="Index__video-cell-widget___3PDlg"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ"><em>14/4</em><small> 28.57%</small></span><div class="Index__video-cell-icon___3Pnub"></div></td>
            <td class="Index__video-cell-widget___3PDlg"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ"><em>594/489</em><small> 82.32%</small></span><div class="Index__video-cell-icon___3Pnub"></div></td>
            <td class="Index__simple-cell-widget___1BYWx"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ">66.7</span></td>
            <td class="Index__video-cell-widget___3PDlg"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ"><em>130</em><small>12/43/75</small></span><div class="Index__video-cell-icon___3Pnub"></div></td>
            <td class="Index__video-cell-widget___3PDlg"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ"><em>108</em><small>38/48/22</small></span><div class="Index__video-cell-icon___3Pnub"></div></td>
            <td class="Index__video-cell-widget___3PDlg"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ"><em>210/85</em><small> 40.48%</small></span><div class="Index__video-cell-icon___3Pnub"></div></td>
            </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>Sturm Graz</td>
        <td class="Index__video-cell-widget___3PDlg"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ"><em>3-4-3</em><small>80%</small></span></td>
        <td class="Index__video-cell___s1IHu"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ">3</span><div class="Index__video-cell-icon___3Pnub"></div></td><td class="Index__simple-cell-widget___1BYWx"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ">1.73</span></td>
        <td class="Index__video-cell-widget___3PDlg"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ"><em>14/7</em><small> 50%</small></span><div class="Index__video-cell-icon___3Pnub"></div></td>
        <td class="Index__video-cell-widget___3PDlg"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ"><em>484/400</em><small> 82.64%</small></span><div class="Index__video-cell-icon___3Pnub"></div></td>
        <td class="Index__simple-cell-widget___1BYWx"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ">49.41</span></td><td class="Index__video-cell-widget___3PDlg"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ"><em>128</em><small>9/50/69</small></span><div class="Index__video-cell-icon___3Pnub"></div></td>
        <td class="Index__video-cell-widget___3PDlg"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ"><em>101</em><small>33/50/18</small></span><div class="Index__video-cell-icon___3Pnub"></div></td>
        <td class="Index__video-cell-widget___3PDlg"><span class="Index__stat-wrapper___n5jnZ"><em>228/87</em><small> 38.16%</small></span><div class="Index__video-cell-icon___3Pnub"></div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: so, it's missing the lines of the text that have a percent value, or a forward slash.  Is this an encoding issue?

Comment: as you can see if you compare these two strings the \n seperates each text in a tag in the line. A column is missing and in some others there should be two values, but there isnt.

Comment: if you open the page in a browser, and look at the source, what is the content?

Comment: That shouldnt matter but ok: in every 'tr' there is a 'td' with a class in them there is a 'span' with a class and in them there is an 'em' and a 'small'

Comment: With Selenium I get an WebElement for every tr, as I saw in the Debugger the Element has an attribute named text(string). In this there is all the Information that I need, but when I use it or put it into a variable or an array some parts of the string are missing and ontop of that, this only happens on some lines(tr).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could paste into your question the html content of one of those rows that has the problem (the full <tr>).  then I could try to reproduce the problem locally.  (maybe one of the rows that works okay too?)

Comment: Also, can you be more specific about the content you want to put into an array?  are you trying to split by "\n"?  there might be a better way.

Comment: Content = string, yeah 'splitlines()' and no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can't reproduce the problem that you are reporting using python 2.7.10.
If I were to speculate, you mentioned that you were looking at "t" in a debugger at some later point...did some other code manipulate "t"?

I also would suggest that if you want to split out all of the different components of each row, you should call out those "em" and "small" elements as separate entities.  Here is some code demonstrating:

```
    driver.get('file://path_to_html_from_above/text_attribute_missing_td_content.html')
    rows = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//table/tbody/tr')))

    for count, e in enumerate(rows):
        line = e.text.splitlines()
        t = e.text
        # this demonstrates that they have the same content
        self.assertEqual(line, t.splitlines())

    # storing a list of lists
    # representing rows of text, but splitting the content of the td in two if it has em and small HTML elements
    table_content = list()
    for row in rows:
        # pull out each column
        cols = row.find_elements_by_xpath('./td')
        r = list()
        for col in cols:
            # if the column has em and small elements grab those
            try:
                em = col.find_element_by_tag_name('em')
                r.append(em.text)
                small = col.find_element_by_tag_name('small')
                r.append(small.text)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                # otherwise, just get straight text
                r.append(col.text)

        table_content.append(r)


    print(table_content)
```

Notice that I changed your XPATH to be specific about finding just trs in the table/tbody.

Comment: I use Python 3.6. t is in a loop where it is overwritten every iteration and it is never used. Assert equal is useless. The thing is even if I I write an IF for the faulty line that changes sometimes without making any changes to the code or that the data on the site changes, so that the t is never used or changed just deklared or that e.text is printed, the string is missing something. just the debugger says that in e(Webelement) theres a string (text) with all. I will try to get it now from the child elements. Thanks for the fast reponses.

Comment: You didnt change the XPATH at all

Comment: I tried it going through all td's an em and so on, but this doesnt work either. Funny thing is that Im going through multiple tables and all the faulty lines are all on the same position. So for example if the 8th line in the first table doesnt work, then this also applies to all other tables.

Comment: Interesting that the problem was solved using firefox instead of chrome!

Comment: Just to be clear...your XPATH was "//table//tbody//tr", and mine is "//table/tbody/tr".  the use of the single "/" vs "//" does make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

First I thought it was the Webdriver so I used the Firefox one. The Solution was to use InnerHTML.